# Change Colors in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

The script that starts my Angular CLI development Web server produces almost illegible error messages, such as the following.[[image: TypeScript Compiler Diagonstics]]

I would much prefer something like this:[[image: Legible Error Message]

Before I start digging into the oodles of configuration files associated with my Angular/CLI installation, I thought that I would start by asking for directions.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do it is to change characters in the output stream of the application that controls the color.

Linux bash:

```
ng serve | tr $INPUTCOLOR $OUTPUTCOLOR
```

or

```
ng serve | sed -r "s/$INPUTCOLOR/$OUTPUTCOLOR/g'
```

Windows PowerShell:

```
ng serve | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $INPUTCOLOR, $OUTPUTCOLOR }
```

The `$INPUTCOLOR` and `$OUTPUTCOLOR` is needed to be set to run the code. This way every red foreground color can be changed with red background and white foreground color.

Comment: This solution implies a pipe, which defeats the purpose of having immediate output in real time. Bear in mind that the server emits output each time the site changes.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by adding `| %{$_ -replace "\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]",""}` to the end of the command. For example:

```
ng build | %{$_ -replace "\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]",""}
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6478

Comment: This just removes the colors, but he wants to replace colors.

Comment: Moreover, maybe I forgot to say that I'm running on Windows. While I've since moved from 7 to 10, more important is that I want the text colors to change in real time, rather than through a filter. While I might be able to implement a filter on Windows, it would, at best, be a kludge. Hence, I prefer a configuration setting.